# Les objets avec l'impératif

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, impératif, trait-d-union

Les objets, sont-ils toujours après le verbe dans une phrase à l'impératif ? Je connais la phrase « Allons-y ! » mais je ne connais pas la règle. Je peux enlever le sujet et mettre le pronom réfléchi après le verbe (s'il existe) mais je ne sais pas ce qu'on fait avec les objets. En cours aujourd'hui j'ai vu la phrase « Vas-t'en ! ». La forme en « vous » est-elle « Allez-vous en ! » ou « Allez-vous-en ! » ? Comment faire la différence ?

Quelqu'un peut-il m'expliquer la règle pour les objets à l'impératif ? Quelle est la différence entre la position des objets directs et des objets indirects à l'impératif ? Est-ce qu'il y a toujours un trait d'union ?

Comment: J'ai édité la question suite à ton commentaire sur la réponse de [lkl](http://french.stackexchange.com/users/7684/lkl), afin de mettre le doigt sur les petites erreurs. Note qu'un espace avant le "!" et le "?" sont [obligatoires](http://grammaire.reverso.net/5_1_10_les_espaces_et_la_ponctuation.shtml) en français.

Comment: @Random merci beaucoup. J'apprends toujours.

Comment: @Random: About spaces, conventions are sometimes different outside of France. As long as the usage is consistent throughout a post there's no reason to change it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dans l'[impératif](https://www.lawlessfrench.com/grammar/imperative-mood/) affirmatif oui : les pronoms se placent toujours après le verbe. Ils sont tous connectés par traits d'union - donc, *allez-vous-en*, *donne-le-moi*.

Exception : *me* et *te* se contractent obligatoirement devant *y* et *en*, comme dans *va-t'en*.

En revanche, dans l'impératif négatif, les pronoms suivent les mêmes règles que tous les autres temps et modes verbaux : les pronoms précèdent le verbe : *ne vous en allez pas*, *ne me le donne pas*.

Comment: Merci beaucoup. Ma classe n'étudie jamais ce règle. Aussi, excusez-moi si j'écrit mal la question.

Comment: Pas de problème, c'est normal ici que l'on corrige les erreurs dans les questions. Si ma résponse vous a aidé, veuillez cliquer sur la flèche (pour dire que c'était utile) et/ou marquer la question résolue.